# After hook error in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe StudentsController do
  fixtures :all

  context "#profile" do
    let(:school) { Factory.create(:school_2) }

    before do
      session[:email] = user.email
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    it "should assign the user to @user" do
      User.stub(:find).with(user.id).and_return(user)
      get :profile
      assigns[:user].should eql(user)
    end
  end
end
```

An error occurred in an after hook:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `original_path_set' for nil:NilClass
occurred at /home/qbadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/view_rendering.rb:121:in `block (2 levels) in <module:ViewRendering>'
```

This is the error I got when running `rspec spec` from the command line. Can anyone help me to figure out what the problem is?.

The RSpec versions I have specified in the Gemfile are:

```
gem 'rspec', '~> 2.13',
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide some code please ?

Comment: When I give the command "rspec spec" in terminal it produces an error like the above. It gets continuously displayed for the whole spec. When checked the path of the error a method named original_path_set is present.But dont know how to fix this.

Comment: can you provide the code of your spec please

Comment: `require 'spec_helper'

describe StudentsController do
  fixtures :all

  context "#profile" do
    let(:school) { Factory.create(:school_1) }

    before do
      session[:email] = user.email
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    it "should assign the user to @user" do
      User.stub(:find).with(user.id).and_return(user)
      get :profile
      assigns[:user].should eql(user)
    end
  end
end'

Comment: please update your question to include the code you just provided and finally please use markdown synax to indent your code :)

Comment: You're getting an error when you run `rspec spec` which runs *all* your tests.  Is there a reason you've included the code of that particular `StudentsController` test?  Is there a particular reason that tests is supposed to be relevant, or is it just a random test you picked to include?

Comment: It is just a random test I picked to be included. The issue occurs when I just run the specs. It shows some path in the error. I dont know whether it is related to my spec code.@AmitKumarGupta

Comment: You wrote it is happening in after_hook - I can't see any after hooks in the code you provided.

Answer (score -1):

In your gemfile you should have something like this in order for rspec to work correctly

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.13.2'
end
```

I also recommand you take a look at the [database_cleaner](http://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner) gem

```
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.0.1'
end
```

Regarding your issue, after little research, it seems there is an issue with how rspec is getting the path of your spec file. Can you confirm that the above specs are written in the following file ?

`spec/controllers/students_controller_spec.rb`

Could you also copy / paste your controllers code please ?

Answer (score -2):

I had this exact issue to day.

It turned out I had forgotten to do a `rake db:test:prepare` after a database change, before running the test suite again.

Comment: I don't think this is a generalised answer, this may be a reason your local setup. Also could be a reason that database cleaner setup is not working properly. Since hooks are basically arbitrary code that you want to execute before and after each example.